# Ubuntu photo backup software

Tags: software-recommendation, backup, android, photo

A long while ago when I used Ubuntu, there was a software that worked with my android phone, where if I took a picture, it would back up to my ubuntu desktop computer once I was on a wifi network (so it didn't use up mobile data).  I remember getting the notice that this software would not be updated or supported anymore at one point.  However, I can't remember the name of that software and android app.

I was wondering if there was a quick and easy photo back up system like that in Ubuntu (or any other linux distro) so I didn't have to manually back up my photos, it would be done automatically once on a wifi connection (and plugged in preferably).

Comment: I'm using rsync but I'm not sure how good it is.